# Are there security problems with storing public ssh keys in a database?

Tags: ssh

We're deploying some IOT devices at work, and I think we're going to be assigning an ssh key to each device and then storing their public key so that we decrypt their traffic.

The private key never leaves the device, and I don't think public keys are secrets. However, I'm not 100% sure that's okay.

Can someone provide insight into the problems (security or otherwise) with this approach?

Comment: How exactly do you intend to get the plain text with only the *public* key? Public keys are not secrets.

Comment: @JohnMahowald I'm not sure I understand your question, but they will specify which public key to use in the header of their HTTP request and we'll get that public key to decrypt their payload. If it decrypts successfully, then they have that devices private key and are authorized to act as that device. Does that answer your question or is there something else?

Comment: @CallMeNorm `we'll get that public key to decrypt their payload` -- The public key cannot be used to decrypt.  The entire point of public/private keys is that it is one way only.  Encrypt with public, decrypt with private.

Comment: I was just reading about keys again today when I had this exact same realization. Thanks for pointing this out. Is there established ways to use public keys for authorization and authentication over HTTP that are accessible?

Answer (score 1):

What are the sizes of the keys? If your RSA keys are not at least 4096 bits they are at risk of being reversed, and your private keys revealed.

Comment: I was planning on using the ed25519 type of key, and it looks like the public key size doesn't change based on the number of bits.

Comment: With ed25519 you are good to go, no worries

Comment: @YevhenStasiv what is your source on the claim that an RSA key less that 4096 bits is not secure? The latest research I can find says 2048 bits is secure until 2030.

Comment: There is no source, it takes little effort to generate a larger key for future-proofing & peace of mind. I think it would be difficult for you to prove to me without a doubt that there is currently no technology in the world that can break 2048 bit RSA keys. In 2013 when Snowden leaks revealed the BULLRUN project many speculated that 1024 bit keys may be compromised. Now considering how many new quantum computing projects are being spun up and accounting for Neven's law (in addition to the leaked BULLRUN project papers) I thought it may be a good idea to advise using a larger key (or ed25519).